# Browserify including entire module when only some parts used (react-addons)

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, reactjs, browserify

I'm using Browserify to bundle serverside react.js code for the client.

However, I have a bad feeling that using a module from within an npm package results in that entire package being bundled by Browserify.

**Q:** Does `require('react-addons').LinkedStateMixin` result in the entire `react-addons` package being bundled into my Browserified JS?

IE: does Browserify treat `require('react-addons').LinkedStateMixin` the same as `require('react-addons')`?

If so, is there any way around this? External tools, Browserify options etc.

Answer (score 2):

Browserify does not have the ability to extract parts of the functionality from a module.

What you can do though, is require the desired module from within `react-addons` like this:

`require('react-addons/lib/LinkedStateMixin')`

This will only include the one module (and it's dependencies) in your bundle. However, you now depend on the internal structure of the module. If the `LinkedStateMixin` is renamed, you will have to change your require statement.

Comment: Ah thanks for the tip. I have found a solution below.

Answer (score 1):

@mantoni was helpful but as this is a `react-addons` specific question i will post my answer.

Don't use `react-addons` and `react` side by side. Instead, when requiring React use `require('react/addons')`. This calls a script at `/addons/` that returns the full React *with* addons.

So for my example:

```
var React = require('react/addons');
var LinkedStateMixin = React.LinkedStateMixin;

//this works as normal!
React.createClass({});
```

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1):

In `ReactJS 0.13.3` if you want to use e.g. `CSSTransitionGroup` you have to do the next:

```
var React = require('react/addons'),
    CSSTransitionGroup = React.addons.CSSTransitionGroup;
```

And all that has to be installed – `npm install react`.